# application/config/doctrine/proxies\__CG__ConcreteCoreEntitySiteType.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory, concrete5

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

When installing concrete5-8.3.1 locally, after installation it shows like this error message:

```
require(C:/xampp/htdocs/testconcrete5-8.3/application/config/doctrine/proxies__CG__ConcreteCoreEntitySiteType.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How to solve this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to /dashboard/system/environment/entities and click on the red "refresh entities" button. That should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Concrete but if you have a Symfony Console or something where you can execute commands I would try the following:

```
doctrine:cache:clear-metadata                               
doctrine:cache:clear-query                                  
doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

> Note: I don't know if the commands above are available as part of Concrete
>   I am talking from the Symfony side where when I have such issues that
>   is how I fixed

Last but not least I would try to [dump](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) the classes using composer:

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```